# How do variables retain their logic in IF statements throughout all operations in OOP?

Tags: python, list, oop, data-structures

I am working with the following script that involves two classes that create a list. It basically works like this. You push a Node instance onto the self.begin attribute (in the List class through the IF-statement condition and it sets self.end to self.begin). During the next push you only go through the ELSE statement and work the self.end attribute (so not touching upon self.begin). However, through the debugging prints I still see the self.begin attribute to get Nodes attached to it. So two things confuse me:

1) Does the IF statement logic keeps retained even in subsequent usages of the push method (wherein you only get to the ELSE statement -- e.g. the logic of self.end = self.begin)?

2) If the logic keeps retained, why does setting self.end to self.begin let you to arrive at a result where the self.begin attribute gets extended with newer nodes?

Hope someone has an answer on this. Below is the script.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, nxt):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt

class List(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.begin = None
        self.end = None

    def push(self, obj):
        node = Node(obj, None)
        if self.begin == None:
            self.begin = node
            self.end = self.begin
        else:
            self.end.next = node
            self.end = node

def push():
    list = List()
    list.push("1")
    list.push("2")
    list.push("3")
    list.push("4")

push()
```

Comment: If your `if` condition is `True`, code within if block is executed, else the code with in `else` block is executed. And it will be performed every time you'll call your function. That's how all the programing languages work.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? What debugging prints?

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing you, what you are asking. `self.begin` is an attribute on the instance. Next time you call a method on that same instance, the `self.begin` attribute is *still there*. This has nothing to do with `if` statements.

Comment: After the first call, `self.begin` and `self.end` refer to the same node. That's why after the second call (which modifies `self.end.next`) the same changes are visible through `self.begin`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: You seem to be confused as to how object orientation works. You used `some_variable = List()` *somewhere*, but you didn't show that code in your question. The `some_variable` is the missing link here, that is a *reference to an instance* and when you call a method on the instance, `self` is set to be a reference to that same object.

Comment: I recommend you read [how Python references work](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), then put your code into the [Python tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/) to visualise what happens for this specific code.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! I have done a quick edit, to show how I push the values into the list (self.begin attribute). So I was indeed primarily confused about the fact that by setting self.end to self.begin, I am basically setting both of the them to the same node. And that all operations I perform in the else statement on self.end, extend everything what is happing on self.begin (e.g. self.begin.next.next etc., however, that is not happening for self.end (probably because of the replacement of that attribute with the node at that moment).. I will look into your resources. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In this case: by setting self.end and self.begin to the same node, all subsequent operations on self.end will logically affect the value of self.begin.